# What regex pattern will match a whole word that contains certain characters?

Tags: regex

I want to match whole words that contain certain letters/characters. For example  the pattern would match all words that contain the letter `l` and `a`, such as `car`, `patrol`, `left`, etc. but it wouldn't match words like `boom`, `turnover`, `digit`, etc.

Comment: Why exactly was this question closed? What about it doesn't meet stack overflow guidelines? It seems like a clear question with a clear answer to me that helped me out; I don't see what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pattern like this should work:

```
\b(?=\w*[al])\w+\b
```

This will match one or more 'word' characters (letters, digits, or underscores) only of it contains an `a` or `l` character. The `\b` around it will match the boundary of that word (e.g. where the next character is a non-word character), so it will capture the entire word.