# How can I match an exact word in a string with a regex?

Tags: regex, vba

I've been struggling to find solution to what sounds like a simple problem.

I need to find a word "HYD" (capital letters) in a text string. I need match to be exact. To clarify, any word/text that has "HYD" in it, but does not equal should **not** be matched. Exception are spaces and symbols.

Find in below examples:

text1 HYD text2

text1,HYD.text2

Ignore in below examples:

text1 HYDROtext2

text1 MYHYD text2

The closest I was able to get was following pattern:

> objRegEx.Pattern = "[^a-z]HYD[^a-z]"

Problem with that is that it will not find "HYD" if string starts or ends with it.

Answer (score 10):

From [Tushar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2025923/tushar)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31827527/how-can-i-match-an-exact-word-in-a-string-with-a-regex/45440100#comment51578120_31827527) <sup>[1]</sup>:

Use `\b` word boundary flags for your solution:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "\bHYD\b"
```

Will hit only strings whose whole value is HYD, not strings where there is HYD embedded with some other characters.

<sup>[1]: which OP confirmed worked in a follow-up comment.</sup>

Comment: try to search `[\b …… \b]*` and it will not found exact phrase in string =(

Comment: @Andrew `\b` inside character classes is a backspace char matching pattern, not a word boundary. `\bHYD\b` is a valid example of matching `HYD` not enclosed with letters, digits or `_`.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested with the regex below and got the results you seem to need :)

`/*HYD/*`

I've tested via http://regexpal.com/

-EDIT:

The real answer you are looking for (i think) is https://stackoverflow.com/a/18936642/3462988

The pattern mentioned there selects the whole word containing HYD.
`\b(?=\w*[HYD])\w+\b`

Comment: Unfortunately neither of examples work. /*HYD/* still finds similar text that I want to ignore. for example: HYDROtext2.

the second example finds a lot more patterns with word HYD in it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need the `RegExp` object - VBA's native `Like` operator can handle this:

```
Const allowedSymbols As String = " ,.\/\-"

If myText Like "*[" & allowedSymbols & "]HYD[" & allowedSymbols & "]*" Then
    Debug.Print "Found"
Else
    Debug.Print "Not Found"
End If
```

If you're absolutely sold on regex though then use this pattern:

```
(^|\b)HYD\b
```

With `MultiLine` and `Global` set to `True` - this pattern will match spaces and symbols, but will also match if "HYD" is the first word in the string:

```
'// These will all match:
text1 HYD text2 
text1,HYD.text2
HYD test1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `InStr(s, "HYD")` instead: `InStr` is a language keyword in VBA and this approach will be faster than using regular expressions.

This will return the position of the first occurrence of `"HYD"` in the `String s`, or 0 if `"HYD"` is not contained.

Comment: problem with Instr is it will return position of any word that has HYD in it. so MYHYDOK will return it and I don't want that. I only want HYD or nothing

Comment: In which case, a regular expression with word boundaries is the way to go.